# "Could not load MySQL preference pane."

Tags: mysql

I am trying to download MySQL on my mac and am having a bit of trouble. After installing it, I went to system preferences and clicked on MySQL and it says "Could not load MySQL preference pane."

I have tried multiple ways to fix this, including deleting the pane, restarting my computer, using homebrew, and updating to the latest version of my computer. I've also followed [this tutorial](https://devmarketer.io/learn/do-not-install-mysql-macos-sierra-how-to-fix/) and it doesn't work. Maybe it's because I'm getting stuck on this step? "This step will open a text editor inside of your terminal, you want to delete the line that says MYSQLCOM=-YES- if you have one."

Any help would be appreciated.